# Showing Friends Link SQL, Database, Asp

Tags: sql, database, facebook, asp-classic

I am trying to recreate a simplified facebook and I have hit another bump.
I am trying to display all the users and weather I am friends with them already, if so ill have a message in

getting the date that they became friends, if theyre not friends I will have a button so they can send an invite.
im not focusing on the becoming friends bit yet, I have a good idea of how im going to do it already.
I am trying to just display all the users with either the message or the button, but I can't get it to work and I don't know where to go with it.

I have 2 tables relating to this, 1 with the user info and a friends link table with a friend id, userid1, userid2, date, accepted.
I have 2 recordsets to go through the database in a loop to get the details, heres the code I have.

```
users.Open"SELECT * FROM ubuser ",conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic
friends.Open"SELECT * FROM ubFriendsLink WHERE (ub_lnkID1 = "& session("ID") &" AND ub_lnkID2 = "&users("usr_ID")&") OR (ub_lnkID2 = "& session("ID") &" AND ub_lnkID1 = "& users("usr_ID")&")",conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic

<%Do While Not users.EOF%>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <%=users("usr_firstname") & "&nbsp;"%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=users("usr_lastname") %>
        </td>
    <% If session("ID") = friends("ub_lnkID1") OR session("ID") = friends("ub_lnkID2") And friends("ub_friends") = True then%>
    <td>
    <p>friends already </p>
    <%response.write session("ID")%>
    <%Response.write friends("ub_lnkID1")%>
    </td>
    <% else if session("ID") = users("usr_ID") then %>
    <p> This is you </p>
    <% else %>
    <td>
    <p> not friends</p>
    </td>

<%
End If
End if
users.MoveNext
Loop%>
```

I have created a few friends links in the table manually, but when I load the page it says I am friends with everyone already, and it shouldnt.
I put the response.write in there to see what my session ID is and what the userid1 is hoping to figer out why its saying im friends with all the users, its saying both my sessionID and the userid1 are both the same.

I'm really stuck with this and would appreciate any help given, thanks

Heres the struture of the tables im using

USERS

```
user_ID  Firstname  Lastname   email     password  

1        bob        smith      b@email   password
2        paul       jones      j@email   password
3        Anne       davies     a@email   password
4        Rob        williams   R@email   password
```

FRIENDS LINK

```
linkID   Userid1   userid2   date      friends

1        1         2         01/01/12  True
2        2         3         01/01/12  False
3        1         4         01/01/12  True
4        4         3         01/01/12  True
```

Comment: Please show the table structure and sample data for the two tables.

Comment: Ive written out some of the tables used for this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that although you are looping through your user recordset, you are only ever looking at the first record in your friendslink recordset. A better way of doing this would be with a database join so you only return one recordset to loop through.

```
users.Open "SELECT ubuser.usr_ID,ubuser.usr_firstname,ubuser.usr_lastname," &_
  "ubFriendsLink.ub_friends FROM ubuser LEFT OUTER JOIN ubFriendsLink ON (" &_
  "ubuser.usr_ID != " & Session("ID") & " AND " &_
  "(ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1=ubuser.usr_ID OR ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2=" &_
  "ubuser.usr_ID) AND (ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1=" & Session("ID") & " OR " &_
  "ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2=" & Session("ID") & ")) ORDER BY " &_
  "ubuser.usr_lastname ASC, ubuser.usr_firstname ASC", _
  conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic

<% Do While Not users.EOF %>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <%= users("usr_firstname") & "&nbsp;" %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= users("usr_lastname") %>
        </td>
    <% If users("ub_friends") = True Then %>
    <td>
    <p>friends already </p>
    </td>
    <% Else If Session("ID") = users("usr_ID") Then %>
    <p> This is you </p>
    <% Else %>
    <td>
    <p> not friends</p>
    </td>

<%
End if
users.MoveNext
Loop%>
```

NOTE: If you don't want yourself to appear in the list at all, change the query to:

```
users.Open "SELECT ubuser.usr_ID,ubuser.usr_firstname,ubuser.usr_lastname," &_
  "ubFriendsLink.ub_friends FROM ubuser LEFT OUTER JOIN ubFriendsLink ON (" &_
  "(ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1=ubuser.usr_ID OR ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2=" &_
  "ubuser.usr_ID) AND (ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1=" & Session("ID") & " OR " &_
  "ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2=" & Session("ID") & ")) WHERE ubuser.usr_ID != " &_
  Session("ID") & " ORDER BY " &_
  "ubuser.usr_lastname ASC, ubuser.usr_firstname ASC", _
  conx, adOpenkeyset, AdLockOptimistic
```

In my example above all the logic is combined into one query. The query returns all users, but if there is a friendslink record that matches both users then it is also returned.

If you are not too familiar with SQL, the first part after SELECT specifies what columns to return (tablename.columnname), LEFT OUTER JOIN means also returns row from another table if they exist (INNER JOIN would only return rows from ubuser if a row from ubfriendslink existed too). I also added an ORDER BY to sort the rows by lastname and then first name.

Comment: WOW John...ThankYou soo much, you will not believe how much I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ive just tried it and it works, however it does show my name on the screen multiple times and does not show all the other users, but Im sure Ill get there
Thanks

Comment: Sorry @user3087466, I think my query was wrong. I have edited my answer, it should work better now.

Comment: Ive just tried it and it comes up wit the error JOIN expression not supported

Comment: I just Google-ed that error and it seems you must be using an Access database which needs a few extra brackets in the query. I have edited my answer and added some extra brackets which should do the trick. Try again and let us know how you go.

Comment: IT WORKS!
Thanks for your help John, I still have my name coming up multiple times, for every friend I have, my name appears, ive been trying to solve it, but for now it will do and i will fix it later.
Thanks a million John!

Comment: If you don't need yourself in the list then you could add WHERE ubuser.usr_ID != " & Session("ID") & " just before the ORDER BY part and that will stop yourself from appearing at all. If you do want yourself in the list then add ubuser.usr_ID != " & Session("ID") & " AND inside the first bracket. I will edit my answer to show both options.

Comment: Brilliant John, thanks. the != was throwing an error so I changed it to <> and it works exactly how I need it to, thanks, couldnt have done it without you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis in your logical statement, it will currently always be true.

```
<% If 
    session("ID") = friends("ub_lnkID1") 
OR  session("ID") = friends("ub_lnkID2") 
AND friends("ub_friends") = True 

then%>
```

...should be...

```
<% If 
(       session("ID") = friends("ub_lnkID1") 
     OR session("ID") = friends("ub_lnkID2") 
)
AND friends("ub_friends") = True 

then%>
```